# how to implement flutter web local notification?

Tags: flutter-web, web-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm wondering if I can implement local notification in flutter web? I saw that I can create local notification for mobile app Android or IOS but is it possible to use it for web app? or any other alternative to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the class `Notification` in `dart:html` package. You can do something like this:

```
import 'dart:html' as web;

Future<void> showNotification( String message ) async {
  var permission = web.Notification.permission;
  if (permission != 'granted') {
    permission = await web.Notification.requestPermission();
  }
  if (permission == 'granted') {
    web.Notification( message );
  }    
}
```

More info about the javascript notification API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: It's not working for me I don't understand why :(

Comment: @YoucefELKAMEL  do you get any error or simply it does nothing?

Comment: Nothing happend, I don't understand why... Do You know how I can have some log or something ? I check the dev console JS their is nothing trigger.